# How to calculate the burnt area for each rectangle in the grids specified and save in CSV

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, javascript

I am new to the Google Earth Engine. I am trying to calculate the burnt area for this gridded region (dividing the region into 24 x 24 grids), and save the area in a CSV file. But I am unable to get to the area.

```js
// Defining the Grid Lines
var lines = [];
var north_lat = 37.0000;
var south_lat = 31.3325;
var west_lon = -109.0502;
var east_lon = -103.0009;
var lat_per_grid = (north_lat - south_lat) / 24;
var lon_per_grid = (east_lon - west_lon) / 24;
for (var i = 0; i <= 24; i++) {
  var lat = north_lat - (i * lat_per_grid);
  var line = ee.Geometry.LineString([west_lon, lat, east_lon, lat]);
  lines.push(ee.Feature(line));
}
for (var i = 0; i <= 24; i++) {
  var lon = west_lon + (i * lon_per_grid);
  var line = ee.Geometry.LineString([lon, north_lat, lon, south_lat]);
  lines.push(ee.Feature(line));
}
var line_fc = ee.FeatureCollection(lines);
print(line_fc)
Map.addLayer(line_fc, {color: 'red'}, 'Grid Lines');

// Calculating burnt areas
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS').filter(
    ee.Filter.date('2022-01-01', '2022-10-30'));
var fires = dataset.select('T21');
var fires_median = fires.median(); // take the median over the time dimension
var firesVis = {
  min: 325.0,
  max: 400.0,
  palette: ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'],
};
Map.addLayer(fires_median, firesVis, 'Fires Median'); // add the median image instead of the collection

var subset = line_fc; // use line_fc instead of blocks and roi
var triplets = fires_median.reduceRegions({
  collection: subset, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
  scale: 1000
}).filter(ee.Filter.neq('sum', null))
  .map(function(f) { 
    return f.set('imageId', fires_median.id());
  });

var format = function(table, rowId, colId) {
  var rows = table.distinct(rowId);
  var joined = ee.Join.saveAll('matches').apply({
    primary: rows, 
    secondary: table, 
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({
      leftField: rowId, 
      rightField: rowId
    })
  });

  return joined.map(function(row) {
    var values = ee.List(row.get('matches'))
      .map(function(feature) {
        feature = ee.Feature(feature);
        return [feature.get(colId), feature.get('sum')];
      });
    return row.select([rowId]).set(ee.Dictionary(values.flatten()));
  });
};

var table1 = format(triplets, 'imageId', 'system:index');
print(table1.size(),'table1');
var desc1 = 'Fire_All_counties';
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: table1, 
  description: desc1, 
  folder: 'rough',
  fileNamePrefix: desc1,
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. You had a bunch of tags for products not mentioned in your Question body. If you did this to increase the number of viewers, I strongly suggest you reconsider(Questions are closed for lack of focus).  You also have an "and" in the title (which also attracts closure votes). If you're having trouble with obtaining the area, the title shouldn't include "and save to CSV".

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code, and you don't really describe what you're trying to achieve in detail. Simply calculating the area of fire for each cell in a grid can be done like this:

```
// Calculates area in m2 for each feature in grid
var areas = ee.Image.pixelArea()
  .updateMask(fireTemperature.mask())
  .reduceRegions({
    collection: grid, 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().setOutputs(['area']), 
    scale: 1000, 
  })
  .filter(ee.Filter.gt('area', 0))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e858b12c18b82b5853c0c92054aee832